# How to develop javascript library like jquery using es6 and webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a simple javascript library to learn something new. I am trying to use es6 and webpack. Everything is working fine but I am stuck at one point, when I try to use it as standalone, I mean when I add `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` to my HTML page and try to access `MyLibrary` variable. It gives me ReferenceError.

Can someone please guide me how to properly setup and compile code so that it could be run without require.js etc.

Comment: Include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your library. Also what exactly do you type on the console that gives you a ReferenceError?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question as mainly being about getting from typescript to 
an importable library which can be included in HTML and used in your `<script>..</script>`.

If this is correct you can use the below minimal setup. At least it should get you started.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "qlib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors  --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.ts',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: ['ts-loader'], 
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        library: 'qlib'
    }
};
```

main.ts: (the library entry point)

```
export class QLib {

    public helloWorld() {
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}

var QInstance = new QLib();
export default QInstance;
```

index.html:

```
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MyLib Testing </title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <script src="dist/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
        <script>
            qlib.helloWorld();
        </script>
        <p>testing</p> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally install, build and start:

```
npm install && npm run build && npm start
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It's working correctly!

Answer (score -3):

To make your own js library you make a js file just like normal and attach it just as you seem to be doing. Your issue might be coming in where you are referencing `MyLibrary`. Are you referencing the variable before your js file loads?

Comment: Please don't answer a question with a question. The Answer section is only meant for answers to the question. Once you get enough reputation, you'll be able to comment on the question.